# Lighttpd as tomcat proxy with static content serving

Tags: proxy, tomcat, lighttpd, static-content

How can I configure Lighttpd to serve static content on specified URL address (eg. `www.my-domain.com/static`) from specified directory (e.g. `/var/www/my-domain/static`) ?

Rest of requests must be passed to tomcat container.

Actually I pass all requests to tomcat (see snippet below). I can't get it to work. So if it's not possible - NO is also answer for me. At least I will stop trying.

```or-tag-here
$HTTP["host"] =~ "www.my-domain.com" {
    proxy.server = ("" => (
                    "tomcat" => (
                            "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                            "port" => 8080,
                            "fix-redirects" => 1
                    )
            )
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to "disable" the proxy on static files (i.e. enable it only on other files):

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "www.my-domain.com" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/my-domain"
    $HTTP["url"] !~ "^/static" {
        proxy.server = ("" => ( "tomcat" => (
            "host" => "127.0.0.1",
            "port" => 8080,
            "fix-redirects" => 1
        ) ) )
    }
}
```

Also try `debug.log-request-handling = "enable"` and check error.log, also see http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/DebugVariables

Answer (score 0):

You just need a new rule to handle static content:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "www.my-domain.com" {
    $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/static" {
        server.document-root = "/var/www/my-domain/static"
    }

    proxy.server = ("" => (
                    "tomcat" => (
                            "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                            "port" => 8080,
                            "fix-redirects" => 1
                    )
            )
    )
}
```

**Edit:**

You could try with [an alias](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModAlias):

```
alias.url = ( "/static" => "/var/www/my-domain/static/" )
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. This one I actually tried but it's not working (don't know why). I'm getting 404 for my static content. Is this solution works for you in practice? I'm using Lighttpd 1.4.28. What's your version?

Comment: I use same version. I didn't test it, I usually forward static content to a dedicated webserver (like nginx) using proxy.server

Comment: I tried exactly your example. It's sadly not working for me any ideas?